# Why don't backreferences work in Python's re.sub when using a replacement function?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Using `re.sub` in Python 2.7, the following example uses a simple backreference:

```
re.sub('-{1,2}', r'\g<0> ', 'pro----gram-files')
```

It outputs the following string as expected:

```
'pro-- -- gram- files'
```

I would expect the following example to be identical, but it is not:

```
def dashrepl(matchobj):
    return r'\g<0> '
re.sub('-{1,2}', dashrepl, 'pro----gram-files')
```

This gives the following unexpected output:

```
'pro\\g<0> \\g<0> gram\\g<0> files'
```

Why do the two examples give different output? Did I miss something in the documentation that explains this? Is there any particular reason that this behavior is preferable to what I expected? Is there a way to use backreferences in a replacement function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there are simpler ways to achieve your goal, you can use them.

As you already see, your replacement function gets a match object as it argument.

This object has, among others, a method `group()` which can be used instead:

```
def dashrepl(matchobj):
    return matchobj.group(0) + ' '
```

which will give exactly your result.

---

But you are completely right - [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) are a bit confusing in that way:

they describe the `repl` argument:

> `repl` can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed.

and

> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

You *could* interpret this as if "the replacement string" returned by the function would also apply to the processment of backslash escapes.

But as this processment is described only for the case that "it is a string", it becomes clearer, but not obvious at the first glance.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass in a function to `re.sub`, it allows you to replace the match with the string that is returned from the function.   Basically, `re.sub` uses different code paths depending on if you pass a function or a string.  And yes, this is in fact desireable.  Consider the case where you want to replace matches of `foo` with `bar` and matches of `baz` with `qux`.  You can then write it as:

```
repdict = {'foo':'bar','baz':'qux'}
re.sub('foo|baz',lambda match: repdict[match.group(0)],'foo')
```

You could argue that you could do this in 2 passes, but you can't do that if `repdict` looks like `{'foo':'baz','baz':'qux'}`

And I don't think you can do that with back-references (at least not easily).

Comment: You can easily get the entire string or individual groups from the match object, but how do you get parts of the string that aren't in a group? For example, if a regular expression were something like "begin.*?(groupstart.*?groupstop).*?end", how could you get the same functionality as backreferences?

Comment: @amcnabb -- I don't know (I don't usually use back-refs).  The thing here is that you have 2 options.  Just be happy :).  In some cases you can work the same thing going with either option.  In other cases, maybe only one of the 2 will work.

Comment: @amcnabb A backreference always refers to a given group. In your example, you get your group with `match.group(1)`.

Comment: @glglgl -- Thanks, I didn't completely grok the question by amcnabb, but with your response, I get it.

Comment: +glglgl, you're right, I don't know why I was confused there.

Comment: You gave an example of why the replace function is useful, but I still don't see *why* the OP saw the difference in the two re.sub calls.

Comment: @jlund3 The result of the respace function is used directly and not interpreted in any way, as the replacement string would be. That's all.